# ¿Cómo creo un bucle que se active donde señale con el mouse?

Tags: javascript, bucles

estoy haciendo un curso de java script y tengo que hacer una lluvia que haga que aparezca una gota en la posición "x" y que en la posición "y"baje constantemente y regrese al llegar al borde.

Esto es lo que llevo de código:

```
var yPositions = [0];

draw = function() {
    background(204, 247, 255);

for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
        noStroke();
        fill(0, 200, 255);
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10);
        yPositions[i] += 5;
        
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la posición del mouse al hacer click en una página puedes añadir un listener al documento de la siguiente manera:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    var x = evt.clientX;
    var y = evt.clientY;
});
```

A partir de ahí ya podrás lanzar el bucle para ir redibujando las gotas